# Lenovo ThinkServer RD440 Remote KVM not working

Tags: java, keyboard-video-mouse, bmc, lenovo

I've got two ThinkServer RD440 servers and equipped them with the extension to use KVM via BMC Web interface. But it's not completely working: When starting the server I can send the F1 key to enter setup via the Java console, but then in BIOS no input is possible. Also Ctrl+H to access RAID-Config and when the installed OS is started no keystrokes (including macros) are recognized.

On server side is the newest BMC firmware installed (68.0.57460) As client I use a Linux Mint 21 with OpenJDK 11 with the security settings adjusted as in https://realtechtalk.com/Avocent_8020_KVM_Java_Icedtea_Viewer_-1702-articles described. Is there anybody out there with an idea how this can be fixed?

I've started the remote viewer application in the console and get these messages:

```
05/26/2023 12:38:58:612: AVSP Session: requesting full screen refresh.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.awt.peer.ComponentPeer java.awt.Window.getPeer()'
    at com.avocent.kvm.nativekeyboard.NativeKVM.a(NativeKVM.java)
    at com.avocent.kvm.nativekeyboard.e.b(e.java)
    at com.avocent.kvm.nativekeyboard.e.windowOpened(e.java)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowOpened(AWTEventMulticaster.java:348)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2075)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:298)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2037)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
NativeKeyboard.focusGained()
05/26/2023 12:38:58:836:  Sending input focus message with focus set to: true

NativeKeyboard.focusLost()
05/26/2023 12:39:07:207:  Sending input focus message with focus set to: false
focus lost, clear the pending key
```

Comment: Are you sure that your KVM solution has been installed properly and is free from bugs? In Java, an "error" is typically an abnormal condition, which should NOT occur in normal operation, in contrast to an "exception". An incompability with some JVM can also be the cause.